# How to repeat Button in RepeatingView

Tags: button, wicket, repeat

How does one add a Button to a RepeatingView? Other components like Label work well but Button is not rendering properly.

My code:

```
RepeatingView repeatingView = new RepeatingView(componentId);
for (...) {
    AjaxButton button = new AjaxButton(repeatingView.newChildId()) {
        ...
    };
    repeatingView.add(button);
 }
```

Edit:

I have decided to create custom column which can render more buttons in one row.
I read that button must be wrapped in panel for correct view.
Let's say the name of custom colum is MultiButtonColumn.

Principle is as follows: Get list L from obejct T, for each property P from item of L create button. Text button is P value.

Java class: MultiButtonColumn.java

```
/**
* @param <T>
* @param <L> list property
* @param <P> item property
*/
public abstract class MultiButtonColumn<T, L, P> extends AbstractColumn<T, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3512450712767559519L;

    private List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
    private String propertyList;
    private String property;

    public MultiButtonColumn(IModel<String> displayModel, final String propertyList, final String property) {
        super(displayModel);
        this.propertyList = propertyList;
        this.property = property;
    }

    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> cellItem, String componentId, IModel<T> rowModel) {
        List<L> list = (List<L>) new PropertyModel<L>(rowModel, propertyList).getObject();
        cellItem.add(new RepeaterPanel(componentId, list));
        cellItem.getParent().getParent().setOutputMarkupId(true);
    }

    protected abstract Button newButton(String id, PropertyModel<P> propertyModel);

    private class RepeaterPanel extends Panel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public RepeaterPanel(String id, List<L> list) {
            super(id);

            RepeatingView listItems = new RepeatingView("repeaterPanel");

            for (L l : list) {
                add(new ButtonPanel(listItems.newChildId(), new PropertyModel<P>(l, property)));
            }
            add(listItems);
        }
    }

    // wrap button to panel for correct view
    private class ButtonPanel extends Panel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ButtonPanel(String id, PropertyModel<P> propertyModel) {
            super(id);
            Button button = newButton("button", propertyModel);
            buttonList.add(button);
            add(button);
        }

    }

    public List<Button> getButtonList() {
        return buttonList;
    }

}
```

Html: MultiButtonColumn$RepeaterPanel.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<wicket:panel xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <div wicket:id="repeaterPanel" />       
</wicket:panel>
```

But I have trouble with MarkUp in MultiButtonColumn class.

```
Last cause: Failed to find markup file associated. ButtonPanel: [ButtonPanel [Component id = 1]]

Root cause:

org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Failed to find markup file associated. ButtonPanel: [ButtonPanel [Component id = 1]]
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.getMarkup(AssociatedMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:97)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.getMarkup(MarkupContainer.java:451)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getMarkup(Component.java:743)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getMarkupTag(Component.java:1389)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.getMarkupIdFromMarkup(Component.java:752)
                      .......
```

I have implemented class MultiLabelColumn. The purpose is the same, to render more Label in one row. This class works good.

Difference between MultiLabelColumn.java and MultiButtonColumn.java is that MultiButtonColumn contains 2 panels (Button is wrapped in Panel and Panel is wrapped in Repeater Panel) while MultiLabelColumn contains only 1 panel (Labels are wrapped in RepeaterPanel).

Comment: Can you add you html for this code?

Comment: RepeatingView is a part of DataTable, specifically is placed in Cell due to render more rows than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you don't have an associated markup file.  You need to create a `ButtonPanel.html`.

But instead of creating your `RepeaterPanel`, I suggest just using a [ListView](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html), which already has the functionality you desire.

Comment: text is add in button body